# can't get ng-watch to work with buttons and

Tags: angularjs

I've created a drop down list like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control input-sm" id="sel1" ng-model="yAxistm" ng-model-options="{timezone: '-0500', updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 1, 'blur': 0 }, allowInvalid: false}">
    <option value="yr">Yearly</option>
    <option value="qtr">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="mth">Monthly</option>                 
  </select>
</div>
```

but now am trying to create it as a buttons but can't get it to pass the value's into the controller...

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="yAxistm" uib-btn-radio="yr" value="yr">Yearly</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="yAxistm" uib-btn-radio="qtr" value="qtr">Quarterly</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="yAxistm" uib-btn-radio="mth" value="mth">Monthly</label>
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong here??

---EDIT---

In my controller, I use ng-watch then to see when the values have changed like this:

```
$scope.$watchGroup[('yAxistm1', 'chrtTyp'], function(newval, oldval) {
//do something
    });
```

Comment: Use ng-click(updateCharts(yAxistm)) instead of ng-change(updateCharts(yAxistm)).

Comment: tried ng-change but still getting the same behavior...`yAxistm` still shows as undefined in the controller

Comment: `yAxistm` what value you want to get from it?

Comment: @user2061886, For the name of the classes I can tell you're using bootstrap. Is that right?

Comment: yep..using bootstrap

Comment: @CharanCherry, yAxistm should return `value`, like when it does with the list box

Comment: In `<select>` `yAxistm` refer selected option to get value. But in second code there is nothing to refer. That is why you are getting `undefined`

Comment: @CharanCherry, I made an edit to my question as I made a mistake on how I'm running the controller...I'm using ng-watch and not ng-change or click...

Comment: Can you please make a plunker or fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try using strings as values for `uib-btn-radio`:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="yAxistm" uib-btn-radio="'yr'" ng-change="updateCharts(yAxistm)">Yearly</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="yAxistm" uib-btn-radio="'qtr'" ng-change="updateCharts(yAxistm)">Quarterly</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="yAxistm" uib-btn-radio="'mth'" ng-change="updateCharts(yAxistm)">Monthly</label>
</div>
```

I removed `value` attribute as well, I don't think it is needed here.

**EDIT**
You can remove `ng-change` attribute as well and update your charts by having this watch in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch('yAxistm', function(newval, oldval) {
  //do something
});
```

This version is simplified (not `watchGroup` since I don't know what is `chrtTyp` for). Basically I just fixed the variable name.

Comment: made a typo in the code, I made an edit to show that I'm using ng-watch and not ng-change...

Answer (score 0):

Here's is what worked with ng-watch...

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="timeoptions" id="yr" autocomplete="off" checked value="yr" ng-model="yAxistm" ng-model-options="{timezone: '-0500', updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 1, 'blur': 0 }, allowInvalid: false}">Yearly
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="timeoptions" id="qtr" autocomplete="off" value="qtr" ng-model="yAxistm" ng-model-options="{timezone: '-0500', updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 1, 'blur': 0 }, allowInvalid: false}">Quarterly
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="timeoptions" id="mth" autocomplete="off" value="mth" ng-model="yAxistm" ng-model-options="{timezone: '-0500', updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 1, 'blur': 0 }, allowInvalid: false}">Monthly
    </label>
</div>
```